Is there a way to use both insert and update in cascade option of typeorm with Domain Driven Design?
In one of my project I am using Domain Driven Desing. with this I have an aggregate which governs inserting its child elements and updating them, so i have one to many relationship between the parent and the child entities. the one side being the aggregate root. so when I try to insert a child entity in the childs collection, type orm expect the updated values for already existing child element (throws an exception saying update values are not defined,since I have set both update,insert in cascade in parent entity), but the intent only to insert the new child element, the cascade : update should be there , because there are other use cases where I need to update child elements through the aggregate root.
i undertand that update can be done using the child repo, only having the cascade :['insert'] is set. but that defeats the purpose of having the aggregate root, can you guys help me to get this issue resolved.

Would it be possible to decouple the domain logic (the aggregate & its entities and/or value objects) from the persistence logic ?
Fetching & saving the aggregate would be governed from the application service rather than from the aggregate.

Yes Fouad , what you say is correct, I have already implemented the CQRS pattern to segregate writing and reading.

Thank you guys, for your efforts, by the way I found the issue, Actually there was an issue of the mapper, in my DDD molde, in which i transform persistent to model and wise versa, so there was mapping issue which caused incorrect mapping.
Thank you all again.
